# systemd: Custom snmpd .so agent randomly able and unable to write custom information under /etc/snmp/

Tags: systemd

I have created a dynamically loadable object .so agent for snmpd. The agent takes care of responding to some of the queries in oid space. The agent writes security information under /etc/snmpd/custom_sec.conf . Everything works fine, but there is one strange problem.

About 50% of system boots everything works fine. I can change the custom_sec.conf just fine. But another 50% of the boots, the snmpd or my .so or systemd gets into strange state where file write writes are denied. I cannot write files. I cannot even write simple debug files from my .so .

If I do systemctl restart snmpd everything works fine regardless of the start condition.

If I make the following change to snmpd.service, everything works:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP) Daemon.
# After=network.target ### CHANGED THIS TO FOLLOWING:
After=multi-user.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf

[Service]
Environment="MIBSDIR=/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/s\
nmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp"
Environment="MIBS="
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/agentx
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/snmpd -Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -I -smux,mteTrigger,mteTriggerConf -f
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
Restart=always
RestartSec=1s

[Install]
# WantedBy=multi-user.target ### CHANGED THIS TO FOLLOWING:
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

It seems I'm not the only one facing problems of this kind, see for example: [Systemd service fails to write file, but only on Cold Boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1515908/systemd-service-fails-to-write-file-but-only-on-cold-boot)

Can anyone tell me why I can write files always when the only change I have made is postponing start of snmpd ?

**EDIT 2022-03-24 6:44**

Too bad I need 10 reputation to post images, but here are the systemd boot graphs:

http://m.asuka.fi/uploads/startup_order_nonworking.svg

http://m.asuka.fi/uploads/startup_order_working.svg

What is puzzling me is that in startup_order_working.svg the snmpd is not visible at all...

**EDIT 2022-03-24 11:16**

For a while I had zeroed in on the target. I thought I need to have snmpd.service run after systemd-user-sessions.service . But I'm back to the After=multi-user.target / WantedBy=graphical.target solution. It is the only thing working. Is this a bug in systemd, snmpd or both?

Comment: Why do you need to have snmpd after multi-user.target in the first place? What makes it special compared to all other services?

Comment: I do not want to have snmpd after multi-user.target . But I must, otherwise snmpd fails to write to file.

Comment: No, that's very far from the actual reason why it fails to write to the file. multi-user.target alone doesn't make any changes to the filesystem, it's always a specific .service or a .mount – for example, systemd-remount-fs.service (though unlikely to be the problem as all services implicitly have an After for it).

Comment: What is the _actual error_ being reported whenever you try to create the file? Do you get an EROFS, or an EPERM, or something else? Does the error depend on the file location (/etc vs /var vs /tmp)?

Comment: I will check. I hope I'll get printf output via systemctl status. Right now I purged my yocto cache and I am rebuilding, gonna take hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem. It was quite mundane in the end.

My .so was also interfacing with mosquitto, but the broker most of the time started after snmpd/.so . My code did not check if the mosquitto_connect() actually succeeded. So actually none of the inbound MQTT messages were getting trough. Those messages would have instructed the .so to change the security file under /etc/snmp/ . But nothing went trough and no logging / printf lines were reached.

I changed snmpd.service like this:

```
[Unit]
After=network.target mosquitto.service
```

Now it works every time. I should maybe make the snmpd exit if .so is unable to connect to the MQTT broker. But it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the `ld.so.cache` file which is generated by `ldconfig.service`.
See `sudo systemctl edit ldconfig.service --full` which just runs `ldconfig -X` to rebuild the ld.so.cache file.

Here are some things you could check.

Create a svg file with the last boot - timeline of loaded services. A webbrowser should be able to read that file (better than console).

```
systemd-analyze plot > boot.svg
```

console

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

Is `sudo ldconfig -v` showing your `.so`?
How long does it take to finish?

Comment: Does ld.so.cache need to be re-generated on every boot? (I added the analyze pictures to initial post)

Comment: No, usually `apt`  or `dpkg` is calling `ldconfig` after installs or updates to regenerate the cache. Did you try to disable `apparmor`, just to see if it's blocking? https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor

Comment: I will try to try apparmor thing this week.

Comment: Disabling and even purging apparmor does nothing.